# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.'

Tags: python, django, django-contrib

I'm getting this weird error when I'm trying to run my Django project, more details (Social_Media is the project's name):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\= Programming Office\Django Projects\Social_Media\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\= Programming Office\Django Projects\Social_Media\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 157, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "E:\= Programming Office\Django Projects\Social_Media\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 31, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "E:\= Programming Office\Django Projects\Social_Media\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 78, in get_handler        
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "E:\= Programming Office\Django Projects\Social_Media\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 49, in get_internal_wsgi_application   
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'Social_Media.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Social_Media.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mainapp.apps.MainappConfig',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show your settings and wsgi files?

Comment: @IainShelvington I added wsgi.py, but exactly what part of settings.py?

Comment: can you provide an MRE? also, are you sure you properly installed django? how are you starting the code?

Comment: @NoBlockhit what is an MRE ? I started the code by making a virtual environment then installing Django and making the project, apps, and all the stuff

Comment: @MazenMamdouh please add ```INSTALLED_APPS``` present in your settings.py